# App terminates after about 5 mins after the pressing lock button

Tags: ios, background

While my app is in the foreground if a user presses the lock button the app will resign from activity but should still be ready to start again when the user unlocks their phone. After about 5 mins or so my application ends up being terminated and when they unlock their phone they are back on the home screen. Is this expected behaviour? As far as I know I havn't experienced this situation until I started a new project. Am I doing something wrong here or forgetting some sort of setting?

Comment: Do you have any crash logs? What happens if you run the app in debug mode on physical device?

Comment: seems like on debug mode it's fine, I get no crashes at all.

Answer (score 1):

The Operating System can terminate your application at any time to free resources for other processes that may need them or to conserve battery life.

> "Apps must be prepared for termination to happen at any time and should not wait to save user data or perform other critical tasks. System-initiated termination is a normal part of an app’s life cycle. The system usually terminates apps so that it can reclaim memory and make room for other apps being launched by the user, but the system may also terminate apps that are misbehaving or not responding to events in a timely manner."

([Source: Apple Developer - "The App Life Cycle"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html))

To minimize the likelihood of this happening to your application, look at what processes are running and do what you can to stop/ pause them while the application is not in the foreground.

Regardless how quickly this happens, it's important to design your application to handle the situation where it may be terminated in the background as this is something that can and will happen. Save state and critical information, such that on next launch the user can continue where he left off.